# Correct user associations with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, filterrific

**Edit** I'm still having an issue with displaying programs. I have universities' names showing up correctly, but because programs belong to universities, I'm still not able to get those to show up correctly. The user table has a program_id, and yet I'm still not able to get it working.

I'm fairly new to Rails, and am running into a situation I've not yet encountered.

I have three models: user, university and program. I want the user to be able to choose one university and one program, however each university must be able to have multiple programs, and programs must be specific to each university. (Ex. basket weaving may not be available at University A, but is available at University B). I am also using the Filterrific gem, if that's important to the issue.

I've been looking into the has_one :through associations, and feel that I am 95% of the way there, but just can't quite get there!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :university
    has_one :program, through: :university
end

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
    has_many :users, :through => :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My specific problem is that when displaying a table with a user's particular university and program, I'm only getting the ID, and not the name of that specific university/program. Also - and I'm not sure if this is related or completely separate - but when I look to edit a user, I receive the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /users/6/edit
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column universities.user_id does not exist`

My view that's having this issue is as such:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td class='center'><%= link_to(user.full_name, user_path(user)) %></td>
        <td class='center'><%= user.email %></td>
        <td class='center'><%= user.role.capitalize %></td>
        <td class='center'><%= user.program_id %></td>    <-- Error
        <td class='center'><%= user.university_id %></td>    <-- Error
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

User edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :full_name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :full_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :university %><br>
        <%= f.select :university, options_from_collection_for_select(University.all, 'id', 'name'), {include_blank: true}, {:class => 'select2'} %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :program %><br>
        <%= f.select :program, options_from_collection_for_select(Program.all, 'id', 'name'), {include_blank: true}, {:class => 'select2'} %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-trilogy' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My user controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
            User,
            params[:filterrific],
            :select_options => {
                sorted_by: User.options_for_sorted_by,
                with_university_id: University.options_for_select,
                with_program_id: Program.options_for_select,
            }
        ) or return
        @users = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
```

And finally my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170404205100) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "programs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "universities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",                    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",                    null: false
    t.integer  "role"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,                     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                             null: false
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.integer  "university_id"
    t.string   "time_zone"
    t.integer  "program_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Forgive me if there's some code missing you need to see. Just let me know, I don't post here too often!

```
2.3.3 :006 > university.users
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  class
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:537:in `source_reflection'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:728:in `derive_class_name'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:176:in `class_name'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:728:in `derive_class_name'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:176:in `class_name'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:221:in `klass'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:118:in `klass'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `reader'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:110:in `users'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
... 4 levels...
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: could you post your user edit code to help debug the second issue you mention.

Comment: Edited my post with the user edit code.

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb file? It would be helpful to see what your database setup is.

Comment: Of course, just added it.

Answer (score 1):

based on how you described the project you should update you model:

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :programs
    has_many :users, :through => :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :program
    has_one :university, through: :program
end
```

So you can specific program by university and if you want the user to have just one program he'll have btw one university through that program.

Hope it can help...

Comment: So with something like that, would I be able to call, for example
    <td class='center'><%= user.program %></td>
That doesn't seem to be working for some reason, I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /users
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column programs.user_id does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest a different type of relationship between models

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :programs
    has_many :users
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :universities
    has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :program
    has_one :university
end
```

In this way You can prevent repeatation of data while stating a program or a university. Relationship is managed in combined table generated.
We get many to many relationship between University as it can have multiple programs and one program can be run by multiple universities.
This relationship is scalable i.e. a university specific program can be later opened by other

Usages will be as

```
 user.university
 user.program
 university.programs
 university.users
 program.universities
 program.users
```

And so on.
Hope this helps..

Comment: I've been reading that HABTM is not the preferred route to go, and instead a has_many :through association is better. That might just be one of those things that depends on who you talk to though.

Comment: Yes you are right, but here you have many to many relationship between University and Program with both having one to one relationship with user. Unless you create a specific custom table/model, HABTM is a possible solution here.

Comment: When I tried this out, I got the error
    `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /users
    PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column universities.user_id does not exist`

Comment: University `has_many` users. So first select a university object e.g. `university=University.find your_university_id` and then use `university.users` to get all users enlisted in university and to get their ids use `university.users.pluck(:id)`  . To check a particular user in university use `university.users.include?  your_user_object`

Comment: When I tried in rails console to enter `university.users`, I got the error `NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass`. I am hoping to show a list of all users and their attributes in a table, and so I need to show user.university and user.program. Will this route allow me to do that?

Comment: Before applying `university.users` in console, check  `university.nil?` if it's `false` and still you are getting errors for `university.users` post the full error again.

Comment: .nil? did return false. Here is the full error. Also, thank you SO much for your help, this has been haunting me for weeks!

I've included the error at the bottom of the original post because this comment wouldn't allow me to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY figured it out. I'm posting my answer in case anyone else comes across a similar issue.

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :programs
    has_many :users, through: :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :users, through: :university
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university
    belongs_to :program
end
```